# How to pass formData to controller with model using jQuery ajax in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have formData which contains files(not in the form) and form  model  object, Now I want pass model object to controller with formData, I have tried in different ways but not getting..

```
var data = formData; // Which contains files which are not in the form.

 var model = $("#formAddEmployees").serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Employer/AddEmployees?model='+model,
                data:data,      
                success: function (data) {
                   alert("success");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                  alert("Error");
                }
            });



 public ActionResult AddEmployees(ModelClass model)
 {

   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  //Not Getting 
   {
   }

   return Json("",JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
 }
```

I have tried like above, but formData is not Getting..!! please help anyone..

Comment: you really need files outside form? you can use `jquery.form` plugin and serialize all form data with files.

Comment: Tried including `Content Type` tag in ajax call ?

Comment: I think it is not possible, the only option is saving the file in file server

Comment: yes, i think that is the only option..!!